# How to clear the infowindow in gmaps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

My project is single JQM, in that the infowindow is appear for only once in the project. when i moves to another page and back to map page, the infowindow is in dead state. How to recover it.

```
 firstmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long);
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {

                    firstmap.setZoom(10);
                  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      icon:image,
                      position: latlng,
                      map: firstmap
                  });

                  infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', clearWindow);

                }
              } else {
                alert("Geocoding failed to this location " + status);
              }
            });
    }

function clearWindow() {

    if (infowindow) {
         google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(infowindow); 
         infowindow = null;
    }
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    }
```

I need to clear the data inside the infowindow. Suggest me some ideas

Comment: Do you want to close the infowindow or just want to clear the content inside it?

Comment: @DeadMan Hi, just i need to clear the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then just replace the content inside it with the blank :

```
infowindow.setContent('');
```

Comment: No its not showing the infowindow with content for second time

Comment: meaning what. What is happening actually and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to show infowindow with new address everytime. when i navigate to map page. But infowindow is appear once in the project. This is my query? if my post is not clear im sorry

Comment: can you show me it live? Because i have worked a lot on google map so i might help you with this.

Comment: I think its not easy to show in js fiddle. Can u clear my doubt. How infowindow is getting close without i called explicitly.

Comment: If your page is getting refreshed then it will get closed

Comment: Thanks man u gave some hints. Now i need to intiliaze the infowindow everytime if the page getting load?

Comment: Yes you will have to do that and that's the only solution.

Comment: K i will try to implement :) thankz @deadman for spending ur valuable time with my problem